# Asking for a counterexample of a bounded linear map which is not open

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am self studying functional analysis and can someone please give an example of a bounded linear map which is not open .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y\neq \{ 0 \}$ be a normed space. The map $L: X \rightarrow Y,  Lx=0$ is linear, bounded and not open. Linearity and boundedness is clear and it is not open as $L$ maps the open set $X$ to $\{0\}$ which is not open (as $Y\neq \{0\}$).

Answer (score 2):

The Open Mapping Theorem says if $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, any surjective bounded linear 
map from $X$ to $Y$ is open.

Any linear map between normed linear spaces that is not surjective is not open.

If you want your counterexample to be surjective, let $X$ and $Z$ be Banach spaces, $T: X \to Z$ a bounded linear map whose range is not closed, and take $Y = \text{Ran}( T)$ with the norm of $Z$.

Comment: Is there a quick way to see that the restricted map is not open? I can see that in examples I can come up with (like $X=C([0;1], \mathbb{R})$ and $Z=L^2([0;1])$ and $T$ the inclusion map), but I don't see why it is true in general.

Comment: If $T: X \to Y$ is bounded and open, define $S: X/\text{Ker}(T) \to Y$ by $S(x+\text{Ker}(T)) = T(x)$.  Then $S$ is also open, and is one-to-one, so it is an isomorphism onto its range.  But then the range must be complete, and therefore closed in $Z$.

Comment: Very elegant, thanks!